# Rails instance method to edit data object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to condense a large dataset with some rules and then return object.

What I´ve done inside a model is this:

```
class Network < ActiveRecord::Base
  def condense
    self.each do |row|
      #Maybe delete row
    end
    return self
  end
end
```

So maybe I have misunderstood but calling Network.all.condense does not work.

```
undefined method `condense' for #<Network::ActiveRecord_Relation
```

Maybe some more enlightened rails guru can help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a class that takes in the array of `Networks` you want to `condense`

```
class NetworkCondenser
  def initialize(networks)
    @networks = networks
  end

  def call
    @networks.each do |network|
      # do your stuff here
    end
    @networks
  end
end
```

And use it like this, from a controller or the console or whatever.

```
networks = Network.take(100)
condensed_networks = NetworkCondenser.new(networks).call
```

**Edit:**

There is another way, and that is to call the method `condense` on each item in the active record array.

```
class Network < ApplicationRecord
  def condense
    # do your stuff here on a single instance only
    # e.g. name = name.upcase if something
  end
end
```

And then from console or controller invoke that method on each instance in the array.

```
networks = Network.take(100)
networks.each(&:condense)
```

Which solution is better depends on taste and your needs I guess, I would prefer the first one for more complex situations.

Comment: Aah, here we have it! Thank you so much. This was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Even though I don´t understand why you can´t keep working on an instance based directly on the active record array of objects. Would be much better and cleaner. Even with this sollution it feels like 1 step to many

Comment: @JonasUlveseth I updated the answer with a possible solution

Comment: so this networks.each(&:condense) is like an each inside an each then?

Comment: Well, it just calls the `condense` method on each item in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined an instance method, whereas what you want is a `Network`'s singleton method:

```
def self.condense
  # now `self` here is a `Network` class itself
  all.each do |row| # iterate over each instance of the class
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
Network.condense
```

P.S. Be aware, that using `all.each` is very expensive operation because it will load everything into memory before processing - may be there is a way to use database layer to do what you're doing?

Comment: I understand a singleton. And I´ve tried that and it works. But I want the flexibility to work with wathever object is in the instance.

So like Network.take(100).condense

Or Network.where(something: "123").all.condense

Comment: @JonasUlveseth `Network.take(100)` will return an instance of `Array`, and will throw `undefined method 'condence' for...`.

Comment: Yes, I can see why it fails. Just think this is a clean way of doing it and I can´t understand that there is not a way around it. I could just pass the object into whatever method and it will work. But wouldnt it be nice to work with instances like this.

Comment: @JonasUlveseth you can always create a wrapper (as apparently new answer suggests)

Answer (score -1):

The only problem you have is that you don't understand `self`. Here is a basic rule of thumb:

- `self` in an instance method refers to the current object of the class.
- `self` in a class method refers to the class itself.

So can you tell me what are the 2 `self` in your code refer to?

Comment: As I think of it the self refers to the the object of data that is in the instance

So like Network.new , then self has a new object in it. So I thought when initiating a method like this Network.all.condense, I should be able to access Network.all as self